# Not able to debug Azure Functions in Visual Studio Code

Tags: azure-functions

I am trying to do [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/javascript/tutorial/vscode-function-app-http-trigger/tutorial-vscode-serverless-node-install?tabs=bash) to run azure function app using vs code.

I am able to [run it locally](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/javascript/tutorial/vscode-function-app-http-trigger/tutorial-vscode-serverless-node-test-local#run-the-local-serverless-function), but not debug it.

[image: run function app locally using visual studio]

When I browse to http://localhost:7071/api/category, I am getting the response.

But I place a breakpoint(see the above image on line 11), it is supposed to stop, but does not.

I see a difference in the image [shown here in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/javascript/tutorial/vscode-function-app-http-trigger/tutorial-vscode-serverless-node-test-local#run-the-local-serverless-function) with mine.

[image: debugging azure function apps in visual studio code]

Contrast to that, I see a square in my case (see below). Does this make a difference?

[image: debugging azure function apps in visual studio code]

**Update**

Azure Function core tools are already installed. Still the problem

[image: Azure Function Core tools.]

**Update 2**

Its probably the [version of Azure Function Core Tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local?tabs=v4%2Cwindows%2Ccsharp%2Cportal%2Cbash%2Ckeda#v2)

At least with C# Azure Functions, when ever I have 4.x, I am able to debug.

This morning [I started with this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/create-first-function-vs-code-csharp?tabs=in-process). And if you scroll down a bit,  its clearly [mentioned 4.x here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/create-first-function-vs-code-csharp?tabs=in-process#configure-your-environment)

I downloaded 4.x and well as 3.x installers, installed, uninstalled, and then re-installed and checked. I see that, at least with C#, I am able to debug with 4.x. But with javascript, I still facing some issues.

[image: Multiple Version of Azure Functions Core Tools]

The [article here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/javascript/tutorial/vscode-function-app-http-trigger/tutorial-vscode-serverless-node-install?tabs=bash) tells us to install [Azure Functions Core Tools V3](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/javascript/tutorial/vscode-function-app-http-trigger/tutorial-vscode-serverless-node-install?tabs=bash#install-the-azure-functions-core-tools-v3). This could probably wrong and must be revisited.

I just saw [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/create-first-function-vs-code-node#configure-your-environment), with JavaScript, its further complicated by the Node js version on my machine. In [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/create-first-function-vs-code-node#configure-your-environment), it says Node.js 10.14.1+, while on my machine, its v14.17.3 while the LTS is at v16.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue but already using `func` cli version `4.0.4544`.  The debugger stops as soon as the functions app starts up.

Answer (score 0):

To debug your typescript function code in Visual studio code, you have to install ***azure function core tools package***.

1. Try installing the above package  from VS Code.
   Press `Ctrl+Shift+p` in your VS Code > Type ***Azure Functions Core Tools*** and Install/Update them.

[image]

2. After installing this, restart your VS Code and run the debugging.
   If you get any errors while installing, then try to install manually by downloading from the web.

Then after download and installing the [azure function core tools v3 version](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools#v3), restart your VS code and now try run the debugging of your application.

3. It will give you the ***function URL*** in the console.
4. Paste that URL in the browser and pass the parameter. While giving the output, it hits the breakpoint if you keep the breakpoint at response context like below:

[image]

Comment: ITs already installed, not sure whats the problem. See the update

Comment: @VivekDev - did you installed manually from the web or through VS Code?

Comment: Installed Manually

Comment: When you started running the application, did you got function url on the terminal?

Comment: Yes, see my first image in the question.

Comment: Hi @HariKrishnaRajoli-MT, can you see my update 2

Comment: If possible, could you take this question into the discussion chat room!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239415/discussion-between-harikrishnarajoli-mt-and-vivekdev).

Answer (score -1):

try to add :
"justMyCode": false

in your launch.json file

worked for me

[launch.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nF5QZ.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: your comment does not work with javascript/typescript. Be great if it did; but the launch.json doesn't work with node and attach.

Answer (score -1):

I know this is a very old thread but I ran into the problem and nothing advised fixed it. However, I discovered that I had an older version of Windows PowerShell that was getting used by VS Code. Upgrading to the current version did not help because the old version was Windows PowerShell and not just powershell (PWSH).

removing the old version from the path solved the issue.

This is the version that worked for me.

Major  Minor  Patch  PreReleaseLabel BuildLabel

---

7      3      7

Comment: Hi @RodneyK , he had already mentioned that he had solved the problem and  it was the problem of the version of azure function. Usually when it comes to third party tools/plugins like these, the power shell and command prompt versions would not fix these problems of breakpoints not working.